# show hide specific line of text

Tags: jquery, text, hide, show

is there anyway of hiding and showing the second line of a text within a specify div with jQuery? the div id is "grape"

I have text that reads

"Cabernet Sauvignon
&
Shiraz"

Sometimes I need the & and sometimes I don't, if it helps it will always be &symbol ??

Comment: Show some code how your layout looks for such line...

Comment: there is a break after each line

Comment: <br> <br/> or <br /> ... and how do you use the & symbol? &  &amp; or &#38; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the text from the `#grape`, then split it and add it as HTML with a newly inserted `<br>`

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWQgW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#grape:contains("Cabernet Sauvignon
&
Shiraz")').each(function(){
     if($(this).children().length < 1) 
          $(this).css("dispaly","none") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var secondLineRequired = false;
if (!secondLineRequired) {
    var text = $("#grape").text().split('&');
    $("#grape").text(text[0]);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg9Et/)

Comment: forgot to add that there is a break after each line! this fiddle removes the third line also?

Comment: More detail in your question would have got you a better answer.